# when I run a php artisan db:seed I got: Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, seed

Sorry for my poor English. I'm creating a project with Laravel 5.5. When I run `php artisan db:seed` to fill the database, I get an error which is:

> In Request.php line 411:
>          Session store not set on request.

```
It's only the specific PostTableSeeder that has this error, and other seeders are ok.
```

The PostTableSeeder code is as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\Post::class)->create();
    }
}
```

and the *postfactory.php*

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(\App\Models\Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'body' => $faker->text,
        'user_id' =>5,
        'category_id' =>5,
    ];
});
```

Anyone could tell me what's the problem?Thank you

Comment: are you listening for Eloquent events?

Comment: yes.I have a listening event for this model?does it has anything to do with this error?

Comment: and that listener is doing something with the session?

Comment: exactly.I know where the problem is.Thank you very much!

Comment: good luck and enjoy ... you might want to add an answer if you are going to leave this question up, for future visitors